# How can I compare the lengths between these two confidence intervals?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, coverage-probability, pivot

Let $X\sim Beta(\theta,1)$. I was asked to find two confidence intervals and compare their lengths.

The first confidence interval is for $Y=-(logX)^{-1}$ over the set $[y/2,y]$.

The second confidence interval is using any pivotal quantity over a confidence interval with the same confidence coefficient as the first confidence interval.

**my work:**

I found the first confidence interval. Through a transformation, I obtain $f_Y(y)=\frac{\theta}{y^2}e^{-\theta/y}, 0<y$. Since the coverage probability of $[y/2,y]$ is a constant 0.239, this is the confidence coefficient.

I found an appropriate transformation for the second confidence interval: $U=X^\theta$, where $f_U(u)=1, 0< u < 1$. Then, I compute its coverage probability as

$P(a < X^\theta < b)=0.239$

$P(log_x(a) < \theta < log_x(b))=0.239$.

However, I do not know how to solve for $a$ or $b$, which are needed to determine the length of this confidence interval.

Comment: Surely it has been mentioned before that $-\theta \ln X$ has an Exp(1) distribution or equivalently $-2\theta \ln X$ has a $\chi^2_2$ distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I like this method a lot. The transformations seem so beautiful. I now have $P(-2log(b)<\chi^2_2<-2log(b))=0.239$. However, I have no idea how to proceed from here to solve for $a$ and $b$, which are needed to obtain the length of the second confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R. $\log_x(a)$ is computed as 'log(a,x))'. For example, 'log10(100)}' is the same as 'log(100,10}'. Both return 2.

```
log10(100)
[1] 2
log(100,10)
[1] 2
```

If you don't use R, then there are mathematical formulas for computing logs with various bases. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code, but how can I apply this to the last line I have in my original post?

Comment: Suppose $X = .5, a = .2, b=.8.$ So you have $\log_x(a) < \theta < \log_x(b),$ Then the endpoints are given by `log(.2,.5)' and 'log(.8,,5)', so endpoints are 2.321928 and 0.3219281. // Seemed obvious; am I missing something? What are your actual numbers?

Comment: How do we know that $X=.5$?

Comment: It's _your_ data $X.$ You tell me.

Comment: I figured that since $X$ is a random variable, we wouldn't know it's value. For example, this can be re-written as $P(-2log(b)<\chi^2_2 < -2log(b))=0.239$, which doesn't rely on the value of the random variable $X$. Is there a way that I can apply your code to solve for $a$ and $b$ here?